# How to replace the content of tinyMCE editor in both text and visual mode using jQuery?

Tags: tinymce, visual-editor, html-editor

I have added a button beside the Add Media button in WordPress' post editor. Its called Insert Content button.

When this button is pressed, it should send a content, either plain text or HTML, into the editor, replacing any text in it.

The code should work in both text and visual mode. How can I do that using jQuery?

Here is an image to further clarify the question:

[image]

Note: There are various answers already but they only answer replacing the text in visual mode.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The first thing to do is to select the active editor. Here we select the editor using its id, which is `content`.

```
var activeEditor = tinyMCE.get('content');
```

Then we use tinyMCE's `setContent`:

```
var activeEditor = tinyMCE.get('content');
var content = 'HTML or plain text content here...';
activeEditor.setContent(content);
```

However, if the editor is in text mode to begin with, after the page has loaded, `activeEditor` will be `null`. So we need to account for that:

```
var activeEditor = tinyMCE.get('content');
var content = 'HTML or plain text content here...';
if(activeEditor!==null){
    activeEditor.setContent(content);
}
```

Since `setContent` only works for tinyMCE, this wont work if the editor is in text mode. So we have to call the textarea directly and update its value:

```
var activeEditor = tinyMCE.get('content');
var content = 'HTML or plain text content here...';
if(activeEditor!==null){
    activeEditor.setContent(content);
} else {
    $('#content').val(content);
}
```

However, another caveat is that if you toggled into visual mode, then toggled back into text mode, `activeEditor` is no longer null, so `setContent` will be called always instead of the textarea. So we have to check for the editor's state. 
To determine the current mode, we monitor the class of div#wp-content-wrap.
Putting it all together:

```
var content = 'HTML or plain text content here...';
if($('#wp-content-wrap').hasClass('html-active')){ // We are in text mode
    $('#content').val(content); // Update the textarea's content
} else { // We are in tinyMCE mode
    var activeEditor = tinyMCE.get('content');
    if(activeEditor!==null){ // Make sure we're not calling setContent on null
        activeEditor.setContent(content); // Update tinyMCE's content
    }
}
```

Comment: Works as expected, should be accepted